# How to initialize a vector of a structure with unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

How to initialize a vector of a structure with unique_ptr? For example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int i;
    unique_ptr<int> p;
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> v{ { 10, make_unique<int>(10) } };
    // error above: cannot convert from initializer-list to vector<A>

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<A> v{ { 10, make_unique<int>(10) } };
```

Within the inner braces of the statement above you're aggregate initializing an instance of `A`, so far so good.

But now there's no way to *move* this instance out of the initializer list, the only this you can do is copy the object. However, copying will fail because the compiler generated copy constructor for `A` is implicitly deleted because of the `unique_ptr` data member. Hence the compilation error.

The only way around this is to not use a braced-init-list. Instead construct an instance of `A` and then use

```
v.push_back(std::move(a));
```

Comment: Or you could create a copy constructor for A.

Comment: @AndyG Sure, but how do you handle a `unique_ptr` within a copy-constructor? Making a copy of the object being pointed to seems kinda odd, but you could do that.

Comment: Yes, via copying. In OPs case, we're only copying an int.